# Django Tutorial : What is get_queryset and why "model = poll" isn't needed?

Tags: python, django

In Django Official Tutorial, "Generic views" are introduced.

We have :

```
(...)
    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'polls/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            """Return the last five published polls."""
            return Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


    class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Poll
        template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
(...)
```

(URL : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/#amend-views)

And it says :

> Each generic view needs to know what model it will be acting upon.
>   This is provided using the model attribute.

1/ Then why don't we have `model = poll` in IndexView class as in DetailView class ?

2/ The second -and maybe related- question is : what is `def get_queryset()` and why do we need it? Counldn't we do just do something like `queryset = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` (just as class atribute)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete answer, based on documentation reading, testing, answers here (thanks to Daniel Roseman and knbk, and half guessing (so please tell if I'm wrong).

Generic Views indeed need to know upon which model to perform. That is because generic views have to execute a query behind the scenes to retrieve the needed object (which will vary between view types, `ListView`, `DetailView` etc).
So when the method `as_view()` is called, firstly `get_queryset()` is called and returns the value of `queryset` attribute. If the latter isn't set, the `all()` method of the model object manager (`poll.objects`) is then called.

Note : While documentation of `ListView`'s `get_queryset()` [isn'nt very clear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset), that of `DetailView` [seems to confirm the above behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) :

> Returns the queryset that will be used to retrieve the object that
>   this view will display. By default, get_queryset() returns the value
>   of the queryset attribute if it is set, otherwise it constructs a
>   QuerySet by calling the all() method on the model attribute’s default
>   manager.

Except it says the `all()` method would be called when I rather think `objects.get(pk=)` would be, as it's "`DetailView`" and not `ListView`.

Finally, as knbk mentionned (and confirmed in the docs), querysets aren't evaluated when slicing without a step parameter, which means in the question's example (= in Django official tutorial), putting `queryset = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` would work just fine as welll (django 1.6 tested).

Answer (score -1):

1. Because we don't need it if we're overriding get_queryset, since we specify the query directly there.
2. No, because the [:5] causes the queryset to be evaluated then and there. If we put that in the model definition, then all requests to the view would use the same 5 items: even if new polls were added, they would never appear in the already-evaluated list (until the server is restarted or the process dies).

Comment: Note that a queryset is still returned if you use slicing without a step parameter. Only when using a step or performing an index lookup, will you get a list or object respectively. You can check the [source code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/models/query.py#L117). So in the case of a simple slice, setting the `queryset` attribute is perfectly fine.

Comment: @knbk Absolutely not. It is true that you will still get a queryset with a simple slice, but that is not the issue: the problem is you get an *evaluated* queryset, which does not change when new data is added to the database.

Comment: Not true, for the same reason that printing a queryset does not evaluate it: an evaluated queryset is simply a queryset where the result cache is filled up, but slicing does not cache the results. Fully tested on Django 1.4: deleting a model will result in 5 new objects, excluding the deleted one, on the next evaluation.

Comment: From the docs: "Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated (partially or fully) also returns a list."